# I am getting NoSuchElementException: No value present

Tags: java

I have two classes one for Customers and one for Transaction. In the transaction, I have a field custID(int) which is also present in Customer. I have all the getter and setter, repos, services, and controller as well. But in one of my methods in the service layer, I am getting NoSuchElementException.

I understand that while the code runs and checks for a record in the database with passed custID, it cannot find the record. But I have mentioned what to do in such case. But my code doesn't move to the code block at all.

Customer Class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "customers")
public class Customer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int custID;
    private String custName;
    private String email;
    private String phone;
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy")
    private LocalDate registrationDate;
```

Transaction Class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "transactions")
public class Transaction {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int transID;
    private int custID;
    private int transAmount;
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy")
    private LocalDate transDate;
```

Service layer from where the issue arises:
TransactionServiceImpl

```
    @Override
    public Transaction addTransaction(CustomerTransaction customerTransaction) {
        Customer customer = customerTransaction.getCustomer();
        Transaction transaction = customerTransaction.getTransaction();
        
        if(customerService.findCustomerByID(transaction.getCustID()) == null) {
            customerService.addCustomer(customer);
            return transactionRepository.save(transaction);
        } else{
            return transactionRepository.save(transaction);
        }
    }
```

What I am doing is, pass a wrapper object CustomerTransaction that has the info for the customer and transaction. And check if the customer is already registered with custID. If its there, it only records the transaction(which works fine as in 'else' block). But if it is not there I want to record the customer and the transaction both as in 'if' block. But it throws the NoSuchElementException: No value present.

But if I am to pass only the customer details via customer's service layer it adds the customer.

CustomerServiceImpl

```
@Override
    public Customer addCustomer(Customer customer) {
        
        return customerRepository.save(customer);
    }
```

Postman Requests:
For customer only:

```
        "custName": "Bibek Bhattarai",
        "email": "spongebob@gmail.com",
        "phone": 9803064423,
        "registrationDate": "03-01-2023"
    }
```

For customerTransaction:

```
{
    "customer":{
        "custName": "Sponge Bob",
        "email": "spongebob@gmail.com",
        "phone": 9803064423,
        "registrationDate": "03-01-2023"
    },
    "transaction":{
        "custID":9,
        "transAmount": 5000,
        "transDate": "04-01-2023"
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide detailed error message that you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

You may get this exception because the value returned by `findCustomerByID()` is an [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html) of `Customer` (`Optional<Customer>`) and not `null`.

Instead of `customerService.findCustomerByID(transaction.getCustID()) == null` you should have `customerService.findCustomerByID(transaction.getCustID()).isEmpty()`.

Comment: isEmpty() is not allowed. I dont get the option when I use the '.' operator after ...getCustID())

Comment: Could you show me the code of `customerService.findCustomerByID()` please?